# Conditional raplacement with index shift in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

having following column in dataframe:

```
0
0
0
0
0
5
```

I would like to check for values greater than a threshold. If found, set to zero and move up by the difference value-threshold, setting threshold on the new position. Let's say threshold=3, then the resulting column has to be:

```
0
0
0
3
0
0
```

Any idea for fast transformation?

Comment: This sample doesn't seem representative enough. What happens If I the threshold is 3, there is a value of 5, and again there is a value of 5 two rows below. Should it be zero or 3?

Comment: this cannot happen. The value in the column (let say 5) is the result of a cumulation from another column with 0 or 1 and represents a sum of series: if there are 5 times 1 after each other the value will be 5 at its last position. So the cumulated value cannot be greater than the index difference between two values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this DataFrame:

```
df
Out: 
    A
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   5
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  6
11  0
12  0
```

```
threshold = 3
above_threshold = df['A'] > threshold
df.loc[df[above_threshold].index - (df.loc[above_threshold, 'A'] - 3).values, 'A'] = 3
df.loc[above_threshold, 'A'] = 0
```

```
df
Out: 
    A
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   3
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   3
8   0
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  0
```